# Jacobiano en lmfit de Python con el método de Newton

Tags: python

Estoy usando el paquete lmfit de python. Quiero pasar el jacobiano mediante mi función definida como 'dfunc' pero siempre obtengo error. Os dejo ejemplo del código:

```
def residual(params, x, data):

   a1 = params['amplitude1']
   a2 = params['amplitude2']
   a3 = params['amplitude3']
   c1 = params['frequency1']
   c2 = params['frequency2']
   c3 = params['frequency3']
   sigma1 = params['sigma1']
   sigma2 = params['sigma2']
   sigma3 = params['sigma3']
   m = params['slope']
   n = params['origin']

   model = (a1/(1+((x-c1)**2)/sigma1**2)+a2/(1+((x-c2)**2)/sigma2**2)+a3/(1+((x-c3)**2)/sigma3**2))+m*x+n


return (data-model)


def dfunc(params, x, data):

   a1 = params['amplitude1']
   a2 = params['amplitude2']
   a3 = params['amplitude3']
   c1 = params['frequency1']
   c2 = params['frequency2']
   c3 = params['frequency3']
   sigma1 = params['sigma1']
   sigma2 = params['sigma2']
   sigma3 = params['sigma3']
   m = params['slope']
   n = params['origin']

   df_da1 = (1/(1+((x-c1)**2)/sigma1**2))
   df_dc1 = (2*a1*(x-c1))/(sigma1**2*(1+(x-c1)**2/sigma1**2)**2)
   df_dsigma1 = (2*a1*(x-c1)**2)/(sigma1**3*(1+(x-c1)**2/sigma1**2))

   df_da2 = (1/(1+((x-c2)**2)/sigma2**2))
   df_dc2 = (2*a2*(x-c2))/(sigma2**2*(1+(x-c2)**2/sigma2**2)**2)
   df_dsigma2 = (2*a2*(x-c2)**2)/(sigma2**3*(1+(x-c2)**2/sigma2**2))

   df_da3 = (1/(1+((x-c3)**2)/sigma3**2))
   df_dc3 = (2*a3*(x-c3))/(sigma3**2*(1+(x-c3)**2/sigma3**2)**2)
   df_dsigma3 = (2*a3*(x-c3)**2)/(sigma3**3*(1+(x-c3)**2/sigma3**2))

   df_dm = x 
   df_dn = 0 

   return np.array([df_da1, df_da2, df_da3, df_dc1, df_dc2, df_dc3, df_dsigma1, df_dsigma2, df_dsigma3, df_dm, df_dn])


out = minimize(residual, params, args=(x, data), method = "newton", jac= dfunc(params, x, data))
```

La respuesta es:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Ese error es típico de NumPy cuando se intenta evaluar un array en contexto boleano. Un ejemplo simple que reproduce el mismo error es:  `np.array([1,2]) > 0 and np.array([1,2]) > 1`. Nunca he usado esa biblioteca por lo que puede que se me escape algo obvio, para poder ayudarte mejor si estaría bien saber en que linea te marca el error y estaría perfecto si pudieras aportar un ejemplo mínimo pero  que pudieramos ejecutar y reproducir nosotros el error. En tu código además de los import faltan datos como las variables `x` y `data` para poder ejecutar tu código y reproducir tu mismo problema.